# How to use NOT selector for selector of .on() using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selector, jquery-on

I'm currently using this to select fields:

```
$('body').on('change', '#mainFrom input', function(){
```

How do I apply a not selector for class `listName` ?

I've tried :

```
$('body').not('.listName').on('change', '#mainForm input', function(){
```

Which didn't work.

How do I do this ?

Thanks

Comment: use selector like `'#mainForm input:not(.listName)'`

Comment: What element gets the `listName` class? `body`? `#mainForm`? The `input`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess that the `listName` class will be on the `input`. If so:

```
$('body').on('change', '#mainForm input:not(.listName)', function(){
// ------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or if we guess that it's on `#mainForm`:

```
$('body').on('change', '#mainForm:not(.listName) input', function(){
// ------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or if we guess that it's on `body`, we have to change more:

```
$( document ).on('change', 'body:not(.listName) #mainForm input', function(){
// ^^^^^^^^-----------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks that explains it..  I'll note this for next time as well

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
$('body').on('change', '#mainForm input:not(.listName)', function(){
```